# Ajax Query gives null value

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Everytime I try to do something on my site which includes AJAX query, I get `null` value, but on Post value is not null.

[image: Screenshot]

Function

```
function lawProposePrompCall(v,m,f){
    if(v == 1){
        $.prompt('',{callback: reload, buttons:{Close: 0}});
        $(".jqimessage").hide();
        $(".jqimessage").html('<div style="text-align:center;"><img src="/public/images/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loading" /></div>');
        $('.jqimessage').fadeIn('fast');
        $.post(url+'/ajax-query', { action: "law-propose-acc", data: f.colawtype, data2: f.colawd2, data3: f.colawd3, data4: f.colawd4, data5: f.colawd5, data6: f.colawd6},
            function(data){
                if(data.status==1){
                    $('.jqimessage').html(data.communicat);
                    $('.jqimessage').fadeIn('fast');
                }else{
                    $('.jqimessage').html('Server Error');
                    $('.jqimessage').fadeIn('fast');
                }
            }, "json");
    }
}
```

And how do I properly convert it to JSon code?

Comment: This seems like a server-side issue. Post your server-side code, along with proper tag for the language you're using.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/RPtPUSa6 This is other page code, but with the same issue.

Comment: Your screenshot is looking at `data` passed in the request, not what is sent in the response. Click the Response tab to see what data is being passed into your callback function.

Comment: Response window is empty

Comment: That means your response is empty, hence `data` is null in your callback function. So it's a server-side issue. I would still recommend first checking to see if `data` is null in your callback: `if(!data || data.status !== 1) { ... Server Error ... } else { ... OK ... }`

Comment: Okey I got some error in code. Will try to fix it somehow. Now I know it's not JS fault.

I got this in response `<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot redeclare RecurencyDownRow() (previously declared in C:\xampp\application
\controllers\work-q.php:2) in <b>C:\xampp\application\functions\f_addexp.php</b> on line <b>8</b><br
 />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed one of the RecurencyDownRow() functions and it worked.